# Calling recv hangs after handle is called

Tags: python, sockets, imap

I've got a Python class I'm using to emulate an IMAP server for a unit test. When the `handle()` callback happens, I try to use `recv()` to get the data that just arrived but I'm blocking on the `recv()` call. I thought `recv()` would return with the data that was received but instead, it just sits there.

In case it matters, I can see that the server and main thread are different in the log output.

I'm assuming that this has something to do with the fact that the socket was just opened but no data was sent through it. Do I need to check to see if that's the case before trying to call `recv()`?

I've created the server using:

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass
...
# inside another class, we've got:
def startUp(self):
    server = ThreadedTCPServer(('localhost', 5593), FakeImapServerHandler)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.setDaemon(True)
    server_thread.start()
```

Then inside some other code in our unit test, we try to connect to the fake server:

```
    print("about to connect")
    self.__imapCon = imaplib.IMAP4("localhost", 5593)
    print("about to login") # we never get here
    self.__imapCon.login(Config.config["imapUser"], Config.config["imapPassw"])
```

The server is implemented like:

```
class FakeImapServerHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print("handling request")
        incoming = self.request.recv(1024)
        print("request was: " + incoming ) # never get here
```

Comment: Does your call to `imaplib.IMAP4()` ever time out or throw an exception?

Comment: Per the IMAP protocol, servers speak first, sending an OK greeting to the client. Both your server and client seem to be trying to recv() from each other at the same time.

Comment: Would the unit tests for IMAPClient (http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) be useful?

Comment: @samplebias, you're right. I needed to have the handle method send a server ready message: "* OK IMAP3 Server Ready". You should post an answer below instead of a comment.

Comment: @Acorn, we've got a client library that works, just need to fake out the server side to test some other code (not the client itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posted as an answer this time) Per the IMAP protocol, servers speak first, sending an OK greeting to the client. Both your server and client seem to be trying to recv() from each other at the same time:

```
atlas% telnet chaos 143
Trying 192.168.1.5...
Connected to chaos
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK chaos Cyrus IMAP4 v2.2.13-Debian-2.2.13-19 server ready
```